# Writing the letter A to a file in binary mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

In Python 3 these statements are True:

```
ord('A') == 65
chr(65) == 'A'
bin(65) == '0b1000001'
hex(65) == '0x41'
int(b'1000001',2) == 65
```

Given the integer `i = 65`, how do I in Python 3 open a file in binary mode and write the byte `01000001` to file?

Despite being simple, I haven't been able to find a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use any of the forms below, according to the needs of your program. They all do precisely the same thing -- write one byte to the output file.

```
i = 65
with open('outputfile.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes([i]))
    f.write('A'.encode('ascii'))
    f.write(bytes('A', encoding='ascii'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rob! I got the syntax wrong. Probably because I'm sleep deprived. The built-in function bytes is described here: http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes